# Facebook app review - Change platform URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-login

We use Facebook login in our website. We need extended permissions granted, so we plan to submit the Facebook app for review.

We are still in private beta, so our Web platform URL is something like https://beta.foo.com. Once we go live, this will change to https://foo.com.

If the app review is successful for https://beta.foo.com, will we have to submit a review request again when we change the URL to https://foo.com? If so, would that mean we would lose the ability to request extended permission during the period the app is being reviewed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need to resubmit for review if you change your platform URL.

After successfully submitting beta.foo.com for review and then changing the Web platform URL to foo.com all requested permissions remain granted.

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell - We only changed from a subdomain to the main domain.