# facebook app review : review on test url?

Tags: facebook, review

I have got a website using the facebook api.

I have got my test environment, where my web application is deployed, with url : preprod.mycompany.test (this is the url of my company)

I have got a current version of the web application already running on www.clienturl.test (this is the client url)

Can I ask facebook to review on my test url, and then once I deploy the new version on the client site, update the url of my facebook application ?

Does the review process start again if I change the web application url on the facebook application settings page?

Comment: Hi, Yop! Do you have an answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Your question has been answered here:
[Facebook app review - Change platform URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25012718/facebook-app-review-change-platform-url)

You can use a staging URL for the review and change to production post-review without the need to submit for again.